# loop through objects changing order each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list of objects (authors) and want to loop through them printing one attribute (name) of them bold and in the first place followed by the rest of the names each loop, having this output:

**name A**, name B, name C

**name B**, name A, name C

**name C**, name A, name B

I thought I could do this with `except`, but this code:

```
titles.each do |t| 
  ...
  list_without_current_name = t.authors.except(t.author)
  ...
end
```

does not delete the author but gives me the complete list of others

Comment: do you want to delete the author once it gets printed?

Comment: no, it should be visible every time

Comment: every loop should output the first author in bold and other authors of that loop in a random order?

Comment: the other author names should be in alphabetical order.
I also did edit my question, because I forgot the important fact, that it is a association...

Comment: so, what you need is to put for each title, lists of authors starting each list with a different author?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array#permutation` method like this

```
authors = ['Mark Twain', 'George Orwell', 'Ernest Hemingway'] 
authors.permutation.each do |p|
  p.each_with_index {|author, i| i == 0 ? print_bold(author) : print_regular(author)}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
titles.each do |t| 
  t.authors.each do |author|
      first_name = author.name
      other_authors = t.authors.reject do |a|
          a == author
      end
      authors_sorted = other_authors.sort_by do |other_author|
          other_author.name
      end
  end
  #here you output first_name and then authors_sorted
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `a.author` to `a`:

```
authors.each do |a|
  print a
  authors.except(a).each do |b|
    print ", #{b}"
  end
  print "\n"
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. It is an associated model, something went wrong when I was "simplifying"